# Capture pass/fail of Protractor test case for custom reporting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, protractor, automated-tests

I've recently setup Protractor testing for our angular apps at our company - and was looking for a simple way to capture pass/fail status of each scenario in the spec classes. Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried messing with the `jasmine-spec-reporter`, but maybe I was missing something there to extract the data I need. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried things like this:

```
let currentSpec = jasmine.getEnv().currrentSpec, passed = currentSpec.results().passed();
```

but am always getting issues like

> currentSpec not specified

Ideally I would like to capture pass or fail without jasmine reporting, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is actually `specDone` not `afterEach`. You either need to modify the `specDone` function of the reporter you are currently using or build a custom reporter that fits your needs.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html#section-specDone

Create your custom reporter:

```
// myReporter.js
module.exports = {
  specDone: (result) => {
    // do stuff...
  }
}
```

Then in your protractor config you would have something like this:

```
const myReporter = require('myReporter');

// other config properties

onPrepare: function() {
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);        
}
```

Comment: Looks like specDone is for the entire spec file right. I want it to update based on each "it" block but looks like I'll need to have some reporting dependency still.

Comment: It should run for each 'it' block. First line of the docs: `specDone is invoked when an it and its associated beforeEach and afterEach functions have been run.`

Comment: ok that makes sense.. still not exactly sure where to specify the specDone piece of it at. in the spec file or the conf file?

Comment: this is what i have now

        let myReporter = {
            specDone: function (result) {
                if (result.failedExpectations.length > 0) {
                    TEST_STATUS = "FAIL";
                } else {
                    TEST_STATUS = "PASS";
                }
            }
        };
        
        afterEach(function (myReporter) {
            home.reportResults(PROJECT_KEY,
                TEST_CASE_KEY,
                TEST_CYCLE_KEY,
                TEST_STATUS,
                startTime);
        });`

Comment: Is that actually working? You should probably create a separate `myReporter.js` file and then set it up in your `onPrepare` of the protractor config similar to the way other reporters are configured. I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this as well?:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-reporter-2

To have a better error description of the error and adding them to the jasmine reporter:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine2-custom-message

Comment: I have looked into it, but am unable to do what I wish. Basically am wanting to have an AfterEach for each "it" block and that will be like  if (result.status == 'failed') { // code to send results to our api reporting }